# How to iterate over a list which is a subset, in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R and have some issues. I have a dataframe with approx 6700 rows and 1700 columns. I want to run some simulations with a package called "simulator". With this package, you need to put the name of two columns of the dataframe (in the following line of code, they are J,j) and then simulation runs.

```
sim_par <- hapmap2gamete(geno = geno1[,c(J,j)], map = map, ref = ref, chr2exclude = 22)
```

I'd like to increase the automation of the script. I have created a list with two columns, each containing the names of the columns in the dataframe. I would like that the simulation runs through every row of the list. How could I do it? At the moment I have only managed to run the simulation after I subsetted the data frame with a single-column list and then using the following line of code

```
for (J in 1:(ncol(geno1)-1)){
  for (j in (J+1):ncol(geno1)){
```

but this means that I get a lot of simulations that I do not need, I only need the specific ones in the list with the two columns.

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You could specify a condition with `if` statement to run a simulation for cases of interest and let it skip the simulation otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a smaller example data set and expected output example it would help, but it sounds like if you have a data frame of column names you could use `apply()` to pass sets of names into your function.

For example, say you have a function that simply takes the sum of each row here's how you'd apply your function over pairs of column names

```
# Dummy data
df <- data.frame(A = runif(10, min = 0, max = 10), 
                 B = runif(10, min = 0, max = 10), 
                 C = runif(10, min = 0, max = 10), 
                 X = runif(10, min = 10, max = 20), 
                 Y = runif(10, min = -10, max = 0), 
                 Z = runif(10, min = 100, max = 200))
head(df) 

           A        B        C        X          Y        Z
1  1.4750598 8.362330 6.978016 12.21039 -8.5725828 115.7556
2  4.0354462 1.129128 7.344782 11.37921 -6.0101677 157.4816
3  0.4487861 5.458865 1.868728 16.07851 -4.4989306 143.0767
4  6.7159017 9.716656 3.389074 18.60543 -8.8977248 124.7074
5  9.7450640 7.766489 9.853184 10.30856 -5.2577736 138.8847


# Pairs of column names
names <- cbind(J = colnames(df[, 1:3]),
               j = colnames(df[, 4:6]))
names

     J   j  
[1,] "A" "X"
[2,] "B" "Y"
[3,] "C" "Z"


# Custom function
hapmap2gamete <- function(df) {
  rowSums(df)
}

# 1 to apply over rows of data frame of names
results <- apply(names, 1, function(x) hapmap2gamete(df[, c(x)]))


# function results per row
results 


          [,1]       [,2]     [,3]
 [1,] 117.2306 -0.2102531 19.18841
 [2,] 161.5170 -4.8810398 18.72399
 [3,] 143.5255  0.9599347 17.94724
 [4,] 131.4233  0.8189311 21.99450
 [5,] 148.6298  2.5087156 20.16175
 [6,] 143.2299 -0.3145681 20.37046
 [7,] 156.6609 -4.6445246 25.92664
 [8,] 163.0996  4.0362794 19.30689
 [9,] 133.7253  4.4901854 18.26631
[10,] 166.0438  2.2915776 21.57703
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll be working on my script again soon, I'll write any other comment or update that I will have!